# How can I convert CSV file into XML format using Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

[image]So far I have imported the csv file and selected the fields using csv writer.... now what is the easiest way to convert this file.csv from CSV to XML using Python (absolute beginner)?

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('file.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['RECORD_ID', 'FULL_NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'CITY', 'COUNTRY']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want your XML to look like.

Comment: Post the XML sample as text and not as an image. Prune it down to a few rows if too long.

Comment: No, please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) A better explanation still is to tell us what you need it for; saying "I need XML" is a bit like saying "I need Python code" with no other details.

Comment: <?xml .version="1.0" . encoding="UTF-8" . standalone="yes"?>
<CSV_DATA>
<Entity>
    <RECORD_ID>1</RECORD_ID>
    <FULL_NAME>Amber Jennifer Ben</FULL_NAME>
    <ADDRESS>93 Jade locks, Douglasshire, N52 2GN</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Lake Jean</CITY>
    <COUNTRY>United Kingdom</COUNTRY>
</Entity>
<Entity>

Comment: Please add your example to your original post by editing it.

Comment: Can you also add to your edit the `line` from `csv_writer.writerow(line)` which contains the information in your desired xml file (`Lake Jean`, `United Kingdom`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    root = ET.Element('Import')
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as new_file:    
        for line in csv_reader:
            ent = ET.SubElement(root, 'Entity')
            node = ET.SubElement(ent, 'ID')
            node.text = line['RECORD_ID']

            node = ET.SubElement(ent, 'NAME')
            node.text = line['FULL_NAME']

            node = ET.SubElement(ent, 'CITY')
            node.text = line['CITY']

            node = ET.SubElement(ent, 'COUNTRY')
            node.text = line['COUNTRY']

            node = ET.SubElement(ent, 'ADDRESS')
            node.text = line['ADDRESS']

with open('output_file.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ET.dump(root))
```

The idea is to create a root, and then for every row you add a subelement that will contain your row, and then for every column create a subelement to the row and add text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. it is a light-weight version of @ygrog code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

mapping = {'ID':'RECORD_ID','NAME':'FULL_NAME','CITY':'CITY','COUNTRY':'COUNTRY','ADDRESS':'ADDRESS'}
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    root = ET.Element('Import')
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as new_file:    
        for line in csv_reader:
            ent = ET.SubElement(root, 'Entity')
            for k,v in mapping.items():
              node = ET.SubElement(ent, k)
              node.text = line[v]
with open('output_file.xml', 'w') as f:
  xml_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode')
  f.write(xml_str)
```